# Core dumped while using vector<string>

Tags: c++, vector

So on Ubuntu I always get core dumped when trying to execute this function:

```
vector<string> inArray(vector<string> &array1, vector<string> &array2){
    vector<string> result;

        for(int i=0;i<array1.size();i++){

            for(int j=0;j<array2.size();j++){
                  if(array1[i] == array2[j])result.push_back(array1[i]);
            }

        }

      return result;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

EDIT:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> arr1{"arp", "live", "strong"};
    vector<string> arr2{"lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"};

    vector<string> result = inArray(arr1, arr2);

    cout<<result[0];
    cout<<result[1];
    cout<<result[2];

    return 0;
}
```

I was doing Kata on codewars.

Comment: How is this function called?

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: Welcome to SO, and congratulations on your first question.  You may notice your question has been downvoted a few times, as it is not quite of the quality that gets great answers on here. You may find this guide helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Program terminated with signal SIGSEV, segmentation fault

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with that, so the problem is probably in the surrounding code. Perhaps you're passing invalid vectors to it. You need to show how you're using the function. Read about what a [mcve] is.

Comment: Not the cause of the problem, but the parameters should be `const`.

Comment: In this case an empty vector is returned. It probably crashes after the function returns, when you try to apply `[]` to it.

Comment: You try to read `result[0]`, `result[1]`, `result[2]` while `result` is an empty vector. These reads are expected to cause segvault.

Comment: Why do you expect the result to be a vector with three elements when you've built the input vectors so that it will be empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing result[0],result[1],result[2],first check the size of vector result and if it is '0' then return 0 or whatever is given and otherwise return result vector.